# How to count and stop the script after x exceptions or 403

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, count

I have been trying to learn how to proper write a counter and a "stopper" if it has been for example Status 403 x 10 times in a row, or if I hit connection error 10x in a row.

For now I did something like this:

```
import requests
import time
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError, ReadTimeout, RequestException, Timeout

exception_counter = 0

while True:

    try:
        response = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/", timeout=12)

        if response.ok:
            print("Very nice")
            time.sleep(60)

        else:
            print(
                f'[Response -> {response.status_code}]'
                f'[Response Url -> {response.url}]'
            )
            time.sleep(60)

            if response.status_code == 403:
                if exception_counter >= 10:
                    print("Hit limitation of counter: Response [403]")
                    time.sleep(4294968)

                exception_counter += 1

    
    except (ConnectionError) as err:
        print(err)
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
        
        if exception_counter >= 10:
            print(f"Hit limitation of coonnectionerror {err}")
            time.sleep(4294968)
            continue
        
        exception_counter += 1
        continue
        
    except (ReadTimeout, Timeout) as err:
        print(err)
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
        continue

    except RequestException as err:
        print(err)
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
        continue

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
        
        if exception_counter >= 10:
            print(f"Hit limitation of Exception {err}")
            time.sleep(4294968)
            continue
        
        exception_counter += 1
        continue
```

However I do not feel concern that I have done it correct where I do repeat the same code in different places. I wonder how to actually to do it in a proper and correct way compare to what I have done where I repeat the same code in different place

EDIT:

Updated code:

The problem right now is that whenever we have a successful print, I would like to reset the counter but it does not for now.

```
import time

import requests


class ExceptionCounter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def check(self, message):
        self.count += 1
        print(self.count)
        if self.count > 3:
            print(message, 'exceeded 3 counts')
            time.sleep(6000)


exception_counter = ExceptionCounter()


def main():
    while True:
        response = requests.post("https://www.google.se/")

        print(response.status_code)

        if response.ok:
            print("Yay! Now I want to reset my counter because it got successful!")
        else:
            exception_counter.check(f"Ahhhh, wrong status code! {response.status_code}!")

        time.sleep(1)


main()
```

Comment: Given the edit, simply add `exception_counter.count = 0` under `if response.ok:`. I still recommend using the built-in mechanisms for this rather than rolling your own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) is backed by [`urllib3`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), so you can just configure some of the built-in retry functionality instead of rolling your own counter.

The following article is an excellent resource for this, and goes over some other common advanced use-cases with `requests`.

https://findwork.dev/blog/advanced-usage-python-requests-timeouts-retries-hooks/

Here's a modified usage example.

```py
import logging

import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 12  # seconds


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    retry_strategy = Retry(
        total=10,
        backoff_factor=1,
        status_forcelist=[403, 429, 500, 502, 503, 504],
    )
    adapter = TimeoutHTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy)

    http = requests.Session()
    http.mount("https://", adapter)
    http.mount("http://", adapter)

    url = "https://notarealsite.foo/"
    try:
        response = http.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except RequestException:
        logging.exception(f"Problem with request to {url}")


class TimeoutHTTPAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.timeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT
        if "timeout" in kwargs:
            self.timeout = kwargs["timeout"]
            del kwargs["timeout"]
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def send(self, request, **kwargs):
        timeout = kwargs.get("timeout")
        if timeout is None:
            kwargs["timeout"] = self.timeout
        return super().send(request, **kwargs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This sets up logging with `DEBUG` level so you can see what's happening with the retries.

I used your timeout of 12 and added 403, though you should note that 403 is not a valid status for retry. Please see the following for an explanation of why.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

> The HTTP `403 Forbidden` client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
>
> This status is similar to [`401`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401), but in this case, re-authenticating will make no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the advice! Im not quite sure if I really understood what is needed to be done. It seems that there might be some reworks to do with requests adapters to make it work by looking at the article "Retry on failure" - I assume its that part you meant?

Comment: After testing abit. It didnt seem to be what I wanted. As soon as I hit 403. It stops right away instead of continue to retry X times that is given in your examples

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie I updated my answer with a working example and a bit more context. Hope that helps, and feel free to ask more questions!

Comment: Ah I see! Yeah, I tried that but the 403 seems to be more trouble than I thought. I have also updated my thread with new way im doing now. Im not sure if that is also good or does atleast what I want but hte problem is that it does not reset whenever there has been a successful requests

Comment: `403` is not a retry-able status. `403` indicates there's a problem with your code and retrying will not change anything, you must change your request. Perhaps you should give the exact context of your request so we can try to solve the actual issue you're having.

Comment: Well the exact context is the first code I have showed. What im trying to achieve is to have reporter. By that I mean I will send myself a notification is my script reaches amount of time of etc 403, or a special exception etc `HTTPERROR`. My idea was to call a function which I call `report(message="403/ or exception")` and if I reach for example 10 times in a row 403 or the exception. It will notify to myself that there is an issue with my script. Go check it (Reason why I have a long sleep because I dont want it to actually be closed since I run a docker that will auto restart if I exit it)

Comment: So to be simple, I want to have sort of checker that checks for me. *Ok this script has reached 403 10 times in a row. There must been a change, need to notify to my coder that there is an issue* so it will print for me and hold it in a long sleep until then. and this should be applied to different exceptions and/or status_codes as well. So thats my whole point basically. Did it make it more clear :D ?